# What does the preposition "on" mean in these sentences

Tags: prepositions

"You got me on that one"

"He blindsided me on that one"

"You can correct me on that one"

"Trust me on that one"

"Choke me on that one"

In these sentences, what on earth does the "on" mean? I mean, with what intention do native speakers use "on" in those situations. I've already look up the preposition "on" on several dictionaries but couldn't find any usage that I think fits into one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit of a slang-y thing more than a formal one, and these are more expressions than they are phrases where each word means something, so I'll try my best based on how I see/hear this used. 
For a lot of these, on is used kinda like "about" - "trust me on that one" is "trust me about that one"; "you can correct me on that" is "you can correct me about that". "You got me on that" is like "you got me about that". It can also be sort of like "for", if someone says they're "waiting on that". To choke on (whatever) means that's the thing stuck in your throat causing you to choke.